# Is it possible to stop a checkbox from changing when clicked, pending some check?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, checkbox

I came across an situation today where I wanted a checkbox to not change unless an associated ajax call was successful.  By "not change" I mean - if the checkbox was currently checked then it should NOT show as unchecked until the ajax call was completed and was successful.

Example HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="a" />
```

Example (psuedo) jQuery:

```
$("#a").change(function(e) {
    //somehow stop the checkbox from showing as checked in the UI
    $.ajax...
        success: function() {
            //checkbox should now show as checked in the UI
        },
        error: function() {
            //show error to user.  checkbox should still be unchecked.
        }
});
```

Various google searches only turned up references to getting or changing the state of a checkbox.

For now I'm just changing the state of the checkbox back in the case of an error.

I suppose this could be done by using images to represent the checkbox and changing them at the appropriate times, but I'm looking for a solution that uses "native" HTML elements, CSS, and or Javascript (or some Javascript library).  Just curious what stackoverflow users have to say about this.

Thanks!

Comment: You really should consider a different design, like using a button that then is swapped with a checked checkbox, or some other design (maybe ask on [UX.se]?). I would not expect clicking a checkbox to do anything but check or uncheck the checkbox. It may possibly show or hide a separate UI, but that's about it.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Thanks, but I was just curious if this was possible, technically.  In regards to user experience, I agree that using something like an on/off slider may be better if you need to update some boolean values on the fly (as opposed to checking or unchecking a box and then hitting a submit button).  I was just thinking that since there is a built-in element, aka a checkbox, then why not use that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use instead of `change()`, `click()` function and prevent default action in it. Then on success you could manually change the checkbox state.

Here [example](http://jsfiddle.net/cgacv9e7/)

```
$("#a").click(function(e) { 

        $.ajax...
            success: function() {
               $('a').attr('checked','checked')
            },
            error: function() {
                //show error to user.  check box should still be unchecked.
            }
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to stop a checkbox from changing when clicked, pending
>   some check?

Yes, you can temporarily disable the checkbox while your ajax query is running.

---

It seems that you already using jquery, based on that, you can try:

```
$("#a").change(function(e) {
    $("input#a").attr("disabled", true); //disable input

    $.ajax...
        success: function() {
            $("input#a").removeAttr("disabled"); //re-enable input
        },
        error: function() {
            //show error to user.  check box should still be unchecked.
        }
});
```

---

**NOTE:**

You should also enable the `checkbox` inside `error: function()`, but I followed your comment because I don't know what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you should use `jQuery.fn.prop` for setting/getting the checked property

Comment: s/you should use/it is recommended to use/  http://blog.jquery.com/2011/05/12/jquery-1-6-1-released/

Comment: Thanks, I tried disabling it on click but it still changed.

Comment: @PedroLobito I just tried it and the box still shows as checked before it is disabled.

Comment: I've tested the code previously and it worked as intended. I guess you've already found a solution, glad it worked out :)